# How to get specific window ID in the browser on Mac

Tags: macos, browser, gstreamer, firebreath

I have a project using FireBreath and Gstreamer to build my own plugin on Mac.
My plugin chooses Core Graphics to show my video from Gstreamer, and my situation is that Gstreamer opens the other new openGL window to show my video.
This window should be embedded in the browser.

There is a Gst_video_overlay function in Gstreamer, and I could pass the window ID to make my video on specific window. but I have no idea how to get the specific window ID in the browser?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you the short answer:  You can't.

The Window ID belongs to a different process, so it's not something you can use anyway.

The only way you can use OpenGL in a NPAPI plugin on Mac (at least since carbon went away and it switched to cocoa) is to use CoreAnimation and use a OpenGLCALayer